# How to retain the order of items in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

code:

```
import os
import collections

Parameters = collections.OrderedDict()
Parameters = {"current": '50mA', "voltage": '230', "resistance": '40 ohms'}                
Parameters["inductance"] = "37"
Parameters["power"] = "100 watt"

print Parameters

o/p:
{'current': '50mA', 'power': '100 watt', 'voltage': '230', 'inductance': '37', 'resistance': '40 ohms'}
```

Why OrderedDict() has not worked in this code ?

Comment: Because you didn't use it.

Comment: See example for usage of OrderedDict at http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes

Comment: yes, i got my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **replaced** your `OrderedDict` object:

```
Parameters = collections.OrderedDict()
Parameters = {"current": '50mA', "voltage": '230', "resistance": '40 ohms'}
```

See that second `=` line? Now `Parameters` is bound to a regular dictionary, not to the  `OrderedDict()` from the first line anymore.

Pass in elements, *in order* as a sequence of key-value pairs:

```
Parameters = collections.OrderedDict(
    (("current", '50mA'), ("voltage", '230'), ("resistance", '40 ohms'))
)
Parameters["inductance"] = "37"
Parameters["power"] = "100 watt"
```

Demo:

```
>>> import collections
>>> Parameters = collections.OrderedDict(
...     (("current", '50mA'), ("voltage", '230'), ("resistance", '40 ohms'))
... )
>>> Parameters["inductance"] = "37"
>>> Parameters["power"] = "100 watt"
>>> Parameters
OrderedDict([('current', '50mA'), ('voltage', '230'), ('resistance', '40 ohms'), ('inductance', '37'), ('power', '100 watt')])
```

Answer (score 2):

At following line:

```
Parameters = {"current": '50mA', "voltage": '230', "resistance": '40 ohms'}
```

`Parameters`is not an OrderedDict but a simple dict.
Simply change it to the following:

```
Parameters["current"] ='50mA'
Parameters["voltage"] ='230'
Parameters["resistance"] ='40 ohms'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you actually create two objects. First you do create OrderedDict:

```
Parameters = collections.OrderedDict()
```

Then you go ahead and re-use the variable name and create a normal dict, which does not hold the order.

```
Parameters = {"current": '50mA', "voltage": '230', "resistance": '40 ohms'}
```

You should just add each variable one per line.

```
Parameters = collections.OrderedDict()
Parameters["inductance"] = "37"
Parameters["power"] = "100 watt"
```

and so forth.